# KFold Cross Validation does not fix overfitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am separating the features in `X` and `y` then I preprocess my train test data after splitting it with k fold cross validation. After that i fit the train data to my Random Forest Regressor model and calculate the confidence score. Why do i preprocess after splitting? because people tell me that it's more correct to do it that way and i'm keeping that principle since that for the sake of my model performance.

This is my first time using KFold Cross Validation because my model score overifts and i thought i could fix it with cross validation. I'm still confused of how to use this, i have read the documentation and some articles but i do not really catch how do i really imply it to my model but i tried anyway and my model still overfits. Using train test split or cross validation resulting my model score is still 0.999, I do not know what is my mistake since i'm very new using this method but i think maybe i did it wrong so it does not fix the overfitting. Please tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix this

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import scipy.stats as ss
avo_sales = pd.read_csv('avocados.csv')

avo_sales.rename(columns = {'4046':'small PLU sold',
                            '4225':'large PLU sold',
                            '4770':'xlarge PLU sold'},
                 inplace= True)

avo_sales.columns = avo_sales.columns.str.replace(' ','')
x = np.array(avo_sales.drop(['TotalBags','Unnamed:0','year','region','Date'],1))
y = np.array(avo_sales.TotalBags)

# X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)


kf = KFold(n_splits=10)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = x[train_index], x[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]

impC = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
X_train[:,8] = impC.fit_transform(X_train[:,8].reshape(-1,1)).ravel()
X_test[:,8] = impC.transform(X_test[:,8].reshape(-1,1)).ravel()

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
X_train[:,1:8] = imp.fit_transform(X_train[:,1:8])
X_test[:,1:8] = imp.transform(X_test[:,1:8])

le = LabelEncoder()
X_train[:,8] = le.fit_transform(X_train[:,8])
X_test[:,8] = le.transform(X_test[:,8])

rfr = RandomForestRegressor()
rfr.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = rfr.score(X_test, y_test)
print(confidence)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're overfitting is because a non-regularized tree-based model will adjust to the data until all training samples are correctly classified. See for example this image:

[image]

As you can see, this does not generalize well. If you don't specify arguments that regularize the trees, the model will fit the test data poorly because it will basically just learn the noise in the training data. There are many ways to regularize trees in `sklearn`, you can find them [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html). For instance:

- max_features
- min_samples_leaf
- max_depth

With proper regularization, you can get a model that generalizes well to the test data. Look at a regularized model for instance:

[image]

To regularize your model, instantiate the `RandomForestRegressor()` module like this:

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(max_features=0.5, min_samples_leaf=4, max_depth=6)
```

These argument values are arbitrary, it's up to you to find the ones that fit your data best. You can use domain-specific knowledge to choose these values, or a hyperparameter tuning search like `GridSearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV`.

Other than that, imputing the mean and median might bring a lot of noise in your data. I would advise against it unless you had no other choice.

Comment: Reducing overfitting is one of the main difficulties in machine learning. There is no easy way to find the right values. Often, the default values are good, sometimes it isn't the case. Something you can do is use randomizedsearchcv or gridsearchcv to explore many combinations of values. Great to know I solved your issue!

Answer (score 7):

While @NicolasGervais answer gets to the bottom of why your specific model is overfitting, I think there is a conceptual misunderstanding with regards to cross-validation in the original question; you seem to think that:

> Cross-validation is a method that improves the performance of a machine learning model.

But this is *not* the case.

Cross validation is a method that is used to estimate the performance of a given model on unseen data. By itself, it cannot improve the accuracy. 
In other words, the respective scores can tell you if your model is overfitting the training data, but simply applying cross-validation does not make your model better.

Example:
Let's look at a dataset with 10 points, and fit a line through it:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
Y = np.random.randint(0,10,10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,10))

def line(x, slope, intercept):     
    return slope * x + intercept

for i in range(5):

    # note that this is not technically 5-fold cross-validation
    # because I allow the same datapoint to go into the test set
    # several times. For illustrative purposes it is fine imho.
    test_indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(10),2)
    train_indices = list(set(range(10))-set(test_indices))

    # get train and test sets
    X_train, Y_train = X[train_indices], Y[train_indices]
    X_test, Y_test = X[test_indices], Y[test_indices]
    # training set has one feature and multiple entries
    # so, reshape(-1,1)
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = X_train.reshape(-1,1), Y_train.reshape(-1,1), X_test.reshape(-1,1), Y_test.reshape(-1,1)

    # fit and evaluate linear regression
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, Y_train)
    score_train = reg.score(X_train, Y_train)
    score_test = reg.score(X_test, Y_test)

    # extract coefficients from model:
    slope, intercept = reg.coef_[0], reg.intercept_[0]

    print(score_test)
    # show train and test sets
    plt.subplot(5,1,i+1)
    plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, c='k')
    plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test, c='r')

    # draw regression line
    plt.plot(np.arange(10), line(np.arange(10), slope, intercept))
    plt.ylim(0,10)
    plt.xlim(0,10)

    plt.title('train: {:.2f} test: {:.2f}'.format(score_train, score_test))
```

[image]

You can see that the scores on training and test set are vastly different. You can also see that the estimated parameters vary *a lot* with the change of train and test set.

That does not make your linear model any better at all.
But now you know exactly how bad it is :)

Comment: thank you for explaining, sorry, i want to clear out what i'm catching up. So, cross validation **does not fix overfitting** but only **tells** if my model overfits and performing badly?

Comment: It is one way of determining overfitting. If you want to reduce overfitting, you can look into regularization (as pointed out by @NicolasGervais) and more generally into bias/variance tradeoff

Comment: thank you so much for telling me in the first place that i have wrong perspective of cross validation now i understand better :)

Comment: but what if both of my score on train and testing set are really high like 0.97 and 0.99? does this still count as overfitting for both train and test set? i'm so sorry for asking again because what i caught up is overfit is when both train and test has vast different score

Comment: I think you need to read up over/underfitting. It isn't necessarily a question of if an alogrithm is overfitting or not, but more about how much does a given algorithm overfit. As for cross-validation, i think this is a [pretty good introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSytzGwwBVw)